# Проблема со звуком при разработке Android приложения

Tags: android, android-studio, аудио, mediaplayer

Возникла проблема при добавлении в приложение звука - простой щелчок. Звук воспроизводится при нажатии кнопки при помощи MediaPlayer внутри метода, который обрабатывает нажатие кнопки. Формат файла wav.

```
// Воспроизводим звук короткого щелчка при нажатии
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tap_button);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Проблема в том, что он **воспроизводится только по началу**. После 10-30 нажатий перестает воспроизводиться. Приложение продолжает работать нормально.

Сначала подумал, что проблема в формате файла. Перекодировал в mp3 и при нажатии кнопки приложение стало падать. Выдает такую ошибку.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
```

Потом подключил другой, проверенный mp3 файл из предыдущего приложения, в котором все отлично работает. Он стал воспроизводиться, без падения. Но опять возникла изначальная ошибка - после нескольких нажатий звук больше не воспроизводится.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Почему звук пропадает???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходя из моего небольшого опыта "общения" с `MediaPlayer`, штука весьма сложная для контроля, начиная от ньюансов цепочки `prepare() start() stop() release()`, заканчивая отлавливанием `onAudioFocusChange`. Думаю, в Вашем случае, проще будет воспользоваться классом `SoundPool`.

Comment: Просто странно что в другом моем приложении, при одинаковых условиях, MediaPlayer работает идеально. Сейчас да, пришлось перейти на SoundPool. И кстати в документации написано, что при использовании `.create` подготовка и прочее в MediaPlayer происходит автоматически.